# Outputting MySQL LEFT JOIN in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, left-join

I have made a mysql query like this

```
SELECT 
    forum_subcategories.name_sub, 
    forum_categories.id, 
    forum_categories.name 
FROM 
forum_subcategories 
LEFT JOIN forum_categories ON forum_subcategories.catid = forum_categories.id
```

and when i echo it like this

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<h3><strong>'.$row['name'].' - '.$row['id'].'</strong></h3>';
echo '<h4>'.$row['name_sub'].' - '.$row['id'].'</h4>';
```

I get the following result:

```
Category-1
subcategory belonging to 1

Category-1
subcategory belonging to 1

Category-2
subcategory belonging to 2

Category-2
subcategory belonging to 2

Category-3
subcategory belonging to 3

Category-3
subcategory belonging to 3
```

But the result i am looking for is this:

```
Category-1
subcategory belonging to 1
subcategory belonging to 1

Category-2
subcategory belonging to 2
subcategory belonging to 2

Category-3
subcategory belonging to 3
subcategory belonging to 3
```

How would i achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is correct as it is, this is just a matter of only sending the category as output when it has changed.  Store the category in a variable, and on each loop iteration, check to see if the new value matches the old. If it does not, print it.

```
// variable to hold the current one...
// It starts empty.
$current_category = '';
// Remember whether there's a <div> unclosed
$subcat_div_open = false;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  // Compare to the category of the loop iteration
  if ($row['name'] !== $current_category) {
    // If there's a subcategory <div> open, close it
    if ($subcat_div_open) {
       echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '<h3><strong>'.$row['name'].' - '.$row['id'].'</strong></h3>';
    // Store the new one to compare next time around
    $current_category = $row['name'];
    // Ouput an opening <div> for the subcategories
    // and keep track of its state
    echo '<div>';
    $subcat_div_open = true;
  }
  // Always output the subcategory
  echo '<h4>'.$row['name_sub'].' - '.$row['id'].'</h4>';
}
// Clean up the open div
if ($subcat_div_open) echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Good Clean answer, with some helpful commenting :)
Thank You

Comment: I've reached another problem,
i would like to have the subcategories (name_sub) with the same id be in the same div, but so far i can only create a div for each subcategory

Comment: A `<div>` surrounding the whole group (category `<h3>` and sub categories) or only surrounding the subcategories (not the `<h3>`)?

Comment: a div surrounding the subcategories in each category like this 

`<h3> Category Title </h3>
<div>
<h4> Subcategory </h4>
<h4> Subcategory </h4>
<h4> Subcategory </h4>
</div>`

and so on

Comment: @DanielHolst Ok, added above. It requires a little more state tracking since the div does not enclose the whole structure. There are probably cleaner ways, but this works in context of what you already have.

Comment: works like a charm :)
i do have one last question
i would like lines between the subcategories <hr/>

i've tried to add them after the echo

but i don't want them to appear after the last subforum in the group

I only want them to appear between the entries

Comment: Better than `<hr>` would be to do that with CSS.  Add a `border-bottom` CSS rule to the `h4` and use something like `h4:last-child` on the containing div to prevent the last one from having a line.  If you can't get it, best to ask a new question including the HTML output this PHP generates for the HTML/CSS people around here to assist. (don't post the PHP, just the HTML output from page source)

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```
$last_category = '';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $category = '<h3><strong>'.$row['name'].' - '.$row['id'].'</strong></h3>';
    echo ($category == $last_category) ? '' : $category;
    echo '<h4>'.$row['name_sub'].' - '.$row['id'].'</h4>';
    $last_category = $category;
}
```